Does Importing a Component into Iterated Components in React Have an Impact?
Let's say I have a three components: <Genre /><Book /><DeleteModal />
A genre has multiple books, and I use .map to iterate through each <Book />
Each book can be deleted, when the Modal is displayed.
There are two options I can think of that would handle this.

Importing the DeleteModal once, and feeding each  with a prop
that handles the closing/opening of the Modal.

OR importing the DeleteModal in the Book component.


Am I best importing DeleteModal into each <Book /> component? Or could this affect the performance of the app, as it would be importing that component multiple times?
This is my first 'real' personal app I'm creating and I want to try adopt best practices.

Yes, importing would add a slight extra cost to each rendered components as the code is loaded, but since this code is just a function (either a function component or a constructor if you use class components), the cost is minimal as long as the modal is not rendered (what is imported is just a reference to the function, not the complexity of the component itself).
However, if your pattern is something like <Modal visible={isVisible} ... /> inside Book, you may run into slight performance issues for a very large number of Books as the modals are always rendered. To the best of my knowledge, you will not run into these issues if you do {isVisible && <Modal ... />}, as the component is rendered conditionally.
The best pattern would be to have only one modal in the parent that can be rendered via states, or even better yet, a modal managed imperatively via a global state (like this pattern from the Mantine UI library), as modals can usually be treated as a singleton in an app (you will almost never render multiple modals at the same time). Another approach can be to use native modals, but it may not be ideal for your use case. One last approach would be to trust large libraries like Radix's dialog
All this being said, the performance boost you may get from that will most likely be negligible. Be careful about missing dependencies in useEffect, memoizing big calculations and those types of optimisations, they are more likely to break your code. You can most likely worry about those micro-optimisations later on in your project. Happy coding!
